# Error calling startBuild: User is not authorized to perform: codebuild:StartBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I want to configure CI/CD with AWS Pipelines using AWS CDK.

I initialized my AWS CDK in AWS account using the following command

```
npx cdk bootstrap --context env=prod --profile il-prod
```

After, I deployed my `PipelineStack` using this

```
npx cdk deploy Pipeline --context env=prod --profile il-prod
```

After it's been successfully deployed the deployed pipeline fails with the following message during the build step

```
Error calling startBuild: User: arn:aws:sts::915521058023:assumed-role/Pipeline-
PipelineCodeBuildActionRole226DB0CB-yMIdGC4ozzfo/1706514727988 is not authorized to
perform: codebuild:StartBuild on resource: arn:aws:codebuild:eu-
central-1:915521058023:project/PipelineBuildSynthCdkBuildP-ZTRILHu8CwbK because no 
identity-based policy allows the codebuild:StartBuild action (Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status
 Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 9a698065-9530-4262-
b920-863bbf9e281c; Proxy: null)
```

This is my code

```js
import { SecretValue, Stack, StackProps, pipelines } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { AppStage } from "./app.stage";

interface PipelineStackProps extends StackProps {
  github: {
    branch: string
  }
}

export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
  #props: PipelineStackProps

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    this.#props = props

    this.#init();
  }

  #init() {
    const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, "Pipeline", {
      synth: new pipelines.ShellStep('Synth', {
        input: pipelines.CodePipelineSource.gitHub("owner/project", this.#props.github.branch, {
          authentication: SecretValue.secretsManager("token")
        }),
        commands: [
          "npm ci",
          "npm run build",
          "npx cdk synth"
        ]
      })
    })

    const appStage = new AppStage(this, 'App', { env: this.#props.env })

    pipeline.addStage(appStage)
  }
}
```

I would expect the pipeline to run successfully or at least fail due to some other issue, not because it doesn't have the necessary permissions to start the build.

Did I miss something during the AWS CDK configuration?